# My visualforce PDF does not render webp image

Tags: visualforce, pdf, images, renderas

There is a PDF which worked perfectly rendering png or jpg images, but now the images are being uploaded to salesforce they are webp format.

I have not been able to render this type of images in the pdf. If I remove the renderAs = PDF then the image does render perfectly.

```
  <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, imageId)}"/> //Not Work in PDF
  <apex:image value="data:image;base64,{!datab64}" /> ////Not Work in PDF
```

Has it happened to anyone? is it possible render a webp into a PDF.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDF does not support webp, and Flying Saucer, the PDF renderer for Salesforce (and other programs), does not support webp; it would need to translate the webp file into a JPEG file to be usable in PDF. As a consequence, these images can't be displayed inside the PDF. You'll need to use a supported format. The reason why the page shows the image in the browser is because the browser supports webp, and can therefore display it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @sfdcfox.

Comment: Is there any way to do this conversion in apex code to convert a webp image to jpg and then display this jpg image in the pdf @sfdcfox

Comment: @ojedawinder Not directly. You could probably call an external service (e.g. on Heroku) to do this, but Apex doesn't have good binary support, and I don't know of any JPEG + webp libraries for Apex.